# jQuery jail plugin and image load sometimes does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I tried to load images using the jail plugin. It works but sometimes it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('img.lazy').jail({
        $("table[id*=dgImages] img").jail({
            //callbackAfterEachImage: function () {},
            //callback: (function () { alert("All the images are loaded"); })
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:DataList ID="dgImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" CellPadding="1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="BusyStyles>
            <asp:Image CssClass="lazy" runat="server" id="Image1"  data-href='<%# Eval("photos") %>' BorderWidth="0" alt="" style="width:300px;height:300px;"/>
            <noscript><img class="nolazy" src='<%# Eval("photos") %>' border='0' width="300px" height="300px"/></noscript>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When i load images with the syntax like, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.lazy').jail({
        //callbackAfterEachImage: function () {},
        //callback: (function () { alert("All the images are loaded"); })
    });
});
```

But when I try to load images like this, It does not work, I cannot understand why:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table[id*=dgImages] img").jail({
        //callbackAfterEachImage: function () {},
        //callback: (function () { alert("All the images are loaded"); })
    });
});
```

This plugin also has a callback function which is called when each image loaded. I want to know who the immediate parent of the loading image is. Each image is wrapped in a div so div will be parent. Show me a way, from `callbackAfterEachImage` callback, for getting the reference of immediate parent of the loading image.

As a result I can work with that immediate parent.

Comment: Do you get some error in the javascript console ? Do you get results when you just do `$("table[id*=dgImages] img")` ? Besides you are missing a double-quote in `<div class="BusyStyles>`

Comment: i have got no error but output does not come. i have few other question two...I want to know who the immediate parent of the loading image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the selector `"table[id*=dgImages] img"` looks good.

I have build a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8WR4F/) and i correctly get all the images. I don't know exactly what is the markup generated by the control `<asp:DataList>` though, so i made up something. Maybe your generated markup is slightly different and thus your selector does not work.

One thing maybe, you are missing a double-quote for the class attribute of the div `<div class="BusyStyles>`

---

For the callback `callbackAfterEachImage`, two parameters are passed to the function: the image as a jquery object, and the options of the plugin. To get the immediate parent (the `<div>`) just use `.parent()`:

```
$("table[id*=dgImages] img").jail({
    ...
    callbackAfterEachImage: function ($img, options) {
        var $parent = $img.parent();
        alert('parent id: ' + $parent.attr('id'));
    }
});
```