# jQuery JAIL plugin doesn't load images until scroll event

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a very simple portifolio webpage [1] using jQuery and JAIL plugin [2].
The main element in this webpage is a horizontal list of images in the middle of the page (like a slider).

To load the images in that horizontal list the page fires an ajax POST to an PHP on server and then uses JAIL plugin to load them in browser. At this point the pages load the images visible in Browser's view port. But the rest of images outside the viewport are not loaded until the user point the mouse on the images and fire the scroll. I want all the images load with no trigger event.

I tried some tricks suggested in [3] and [4] but no success.

Can someone help me?

Thanks ;-)

[1] https://www.fabianebello.com.br/newsite

[2] https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL

[3] [jQuery jail plugin and image load sometimes does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687808/jquery-jail-plugin-and-image-load-sometimes-does-not-work)

[4] [jQuery LazyLoad do not load images until scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971151/jquery-lazyload-do-not-load-images-until-scroll)

**Update**

I guess this is the default behaviour of JAIL: for images outside the browser's viewport it waits until an scroll event is fired. I'm not sure about this. Maybe I'm using JAIL in a wrong way. For now I solved my issue (in my specific scenario) firing an

```
$(window).scroll();
```

when the user moves my slider navigator.

Comment: You are using a very old jQuery version (1.5.2). Version 1.9.0 has just been released and could address some problem you are facing.

Comment: Hi @anderson.pimentel, I'm using this version because a dependency (Yoxview plugin) I'm using. I tried use the last jQuery version, but the Yoxiview fail.

Comment: If things are breaking when you update jQuery I'd suggest looking for replacement plugins, else your life is only going to get harder in the future